# fileserver vs DB query speed

Tags: database, key-value, fileserver

I have very simple data that I need to retrieve as quickly as possible:
I have json data that is associated with a hash of an email. So the table looks like this:

```
email_sha256, json
```

and has millions of rows.

I was wondering if one of the following two options would be faster:

```
1 Split the single large table into many smallers (split by alphabetical order)

2 Do not use a DB at all and serve the data as files. i.e. every email hash is the name of a separate file that contains the json data.
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a file for each user (for each email address), looks so wrong for so many aspect:

- If you needs good performance you need a small amount number of file by directory
- DB were created for that, you can have an index to retrieve the information very fast.
- Without a DB you need to have your own lock/synchronization mechanism
- If you are using a DB why using json to store data.
- If you are looking for performance, do not serialize the data to a json.
- What do you mean by "fast", can you quantify this duration/delay ?

Unless (maybe) the information associated with the user are huge (The size must be very superior to one sector). But again in this case, what do you mean by fast.

Comment: The data of the json is not structured. And it does not need to be queried. I basically just want to serve the json string as quickly as possible. Each user requests the same data and it is only queried by the hash. The advantage that I would expect is that I could serve all files over a CDN and could therefore reduce latency